# Database Transaction on Multiple Query

Tags: mysql, transactions

I'm trying out something new on my end that whenever I have a multiple query that inserts / update. I use database transaction for that matter.

```
$this->transaction->beginTransaction();

try {

    $trucker_user->update([
        'username'       => $request->getParam('username'),
        'first_name'     => $request->getParam('first_name'),
        'middle_name'    => $request->getParam('middle_name'),
        'last_name'      => $request->getParam('last_name'),
        'contact_number' => $request->getParam('contact_number'),
        'email'          => $request->getParam('email'),
        'status'         => ($trucker_id) ? 1 : $request->getParam('status')
    ]);

    if ($trucker_id === false) {
        $trucker_user->userTrucker()->update([
            'trucker_id' => $request->getParam('trucker_id')
        ]);
    }

    $this->transaction->commit();
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    $this->transaction->rollBack();
    throw $e;
}
```

So the question is, is it a good practice when I have multiple query that inserts / update I shall be using database transaction for it?

I know it's a good idea to have a transaction when something bad happens it goes rollback. But whenever I use it always in multiple queries isn't a bit kind of overkill?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transaction is a tool designed for guaranteeing consistency. If the first update/insert operation should be rolled back if the second one fails, then the transaction is needed.

In your example, you update a `trucker_user`'s fields and then, under some circumstances, you update also its `id`. The question you should pose to yourself is *"do I want to rollback all the `trucker_user` updates if the `id` update fails?"*

The answer may be yes either because you have to maintain consistency between the two actions, or because, in case the second operation fails, you have to retry it, and doing everything again is easier than finding where the process was interrupted (so that you can start back from there).